# Как обновить записи в Yii2 (одновременно и UpdateAll и UpdateAllCounters)?

Tags: yii2, activerecord, update

Хочу обновить данные в таблице через [Actite Record](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html). Как написать простой SQL-запрос знаю, задача в том, чтобы использовать именно AR. Одно поле обновляем, в другом - рассчитываем новое значение. Проблема именно с тем, как описать выражение [текущее значение + некое число].

```
// $oldID - старый ID группы
// $newID - новый ID группы
// $delta - некое число, которое нужно прибавить к значению поля in_group

// Код, который не работает
Item::updateAll([
   'id_group' => $newID,
   'in_group' => '[[in_group]] + $delta',
], ['=', 'id_group', $oldID]);
```

Методы *updateAllCounters()* и *updateAll()* по отдельности работать не будут из-за ограничений в базе данных: пара **id_group** и **in_group** - это уникальный ключ, поэтому если обновлять, то одновременно.

UPD. Есть вариант с использованием [yii\db\Expression](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-expression.html):

```
// Код, который работает
Item::updateAll([
   'id_group' => $newID,
   'in_group' => new Expression("in_group + {$delta}"),
], ['=', 'id_group', $oldID]);
```

- но он мне не так чтобы нравится. Можно ли обойтись без *Expression*?

Answer (score 1):

При отсутствии объекта `Item`, в ситуации когда вынуждены использовать статическую функцию `updateAll` ваш вариант единственно правильный.

```
Item::updateAll([
    'id_group' => $newID,
    'in_group' => new Expression("in_group + {$delta}"),
], ['=', 'id_group', $oldID]);
```

Минус такого подхода в том что структура базы данных распространяется по проекту. По хорошему нужно скрыть структуру бд за ActiveRecord. Так как в коде присутствует `$oldID`, возможно лучше получить объект ActiveRecord и работать с ним, а не с простой оберткой над SQL.

> Если у меня есть выбор между отсутствием "лишнего" sql-запроса в базу данных и возможностью работать с объектом ActiveRecord, я предпочту ActiveRecord. Я буду заниматься оптимизацией только узких мест проекта, в остальных случаях красота кода для меня важнее производительности.

Получаем объект Item и изменяем его:

```
$item = Item::find()->groupId($oldID)->one();
if (!$item) {
    throw new Exception('Failed to get Item with old id');
}

/**
 * Там же изменяем in_group. Или что-нибудь ещё. 
 * Логика установки идентификатора группы всегда в одном месте.
 */
$item->setGroupId($newID);

$item->save();
if (!$item->save()) {
    throw new Exception('Failed to save Item with new id');
}
```

И вот так клиентский код перестал знать о том что там за структура у базы данных :)

Comment: В этом случае два синхронных обновления потеряют дельту одного из них.

Comment: @Etki Каким образом? В setGroupId будет прописано $this->in_group = $this->in_group + $this->getDelta(). Или дельта как параметр.

Comment: два пользователя приходят на сайт, система для обоих выполняет идентичные действия, считывая одно и то же значение и прибавляя дельту, а затем записывает; если начальное значение 5, а дельта для каждого из запросов составляет 3, то финальное значение должно составить 11, но вместо этого будут выполнены два последовательных запроса на обновления со значением 8. Добро пожаловать в мир со сценариями с параллельным выполнением.

Comment: @Etki Понял, спасибо). Всё верно, мой вариант тут неприменим.